React native not build - Java importing root project - 70% Evaluate Settings
I'm working on a project in react native, suddenly opening visual studio code I see from the bottom bar that the java project is not built, remaining stuck at the Java importing root project - 70% Evaluate Settings phase. Obviously if I execute npm run android, on emulator or device, the app is not built.
I can't understand at all what the problem could come from, especially because it worked before.
I have the environment configured correctly, with environment variables, SDK etc.. since I was already working there.
Can you tell me what this problem comes from?
I updated the java version and checked for errors in native android files and found no errors.

facing the same issue

I'm also facing the same issue.
